# Errors in my method

Tags: java, methods

Both the problems are in the getCity method, labeled in the comments.
any help would be awesome, also if there are any others error that you see as you are reading, i will accept any help i can get.

```
//DO NOT ALTER THE MAIN METHOD
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //determine input file
    String fileName = "coven_consulting.txt";
    //print method to output breakdown
    printReport( fileName );
}

/* printReport - take the file name, open the file, read and process data, print out report
 * input: String fileName - the name of the file containing the data
 * returns: nothing
 */
private static void printReport( String fileName ) {
    //implement this method
}

/* getCity - ask the user for a city, loop unitl the user gives you a valid one
 * input: none
 * returns: String - the name of the validated city
 */
@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
private static String getCity() {
//implement this method, change the return statement to suit your needs
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input;
    String city = "";

    do {
        System.out.print("Which city do you want a report for?");
        input = keyboard.next();

        if (checkValidCity(input) == true ) 
        input = city;
        while (checkValidCity(input) == false);
            System.out.print("Not a city we consult in, try another...");     
    }    //Error: says while expected
    return city;  //Error: says illegal start to expression
}  

private static boolean checkValidCity(String input) {
    //implement this method, change the return statement to suit your needs
    boolean result;
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("Uberwald") || 
        (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("Pseudopolis")) ||
        (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("Quirm")) || 
        (input.equalsIgnoreCase ("AnkhMorpork")))
        result = true;
    else
        result = false;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your syntax. The `while` should be outside the body of `do`.

The correct syntax is:

```
do {
   // code, bla, blaaa
} while (condition);
```

So your code should look like this:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Which city do you want a report for?");
    input = keyboard.next();
    if (checkValidCity(input)) {
        input = city;
    }
    System.out.print("Not a city we consult in, try another...");     
} while (!checkValidCity(input));
```

One hint for you, please while using `if-else` statement, please never forget for brackets `{}`.

Comment: thanks for the help, this fixed it

Comment: Glad it works. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
    // code
}
```

is not a valid expression.

You're looking for `do {} while (booleanExpression);`

Your second error is due to the first one.

---

```
while (checkValidCity(input) == false);
```

You do not need a semicolon at the end, otherwise nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below.Syntax for do while is do { //this } while(condition)

```
  do {
            System.out.print("Which city do you want a report for?");
            input = keyboard.next();



            if (checkValidCity(input) == true ) 
            input = city;


        }     while (checkValidCity(input) == false)
```